# Get data from a different php file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an JQuery function which submits data from a php form to a different php file(`submitForm.php`). The submission works fine and there isn't any problem whatsoever, below is the handler:

```
    submitHandler : function(){                     
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            cache:false,  
            url: "submitForm.php",  
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {                       

            } 
        });
    }
```

Now, I want to be able get data from the submit form (`submitForm.php`), and load it into a different page.

This is my `submitForm.php`

```
   <?php
       $name="Amanda";
       $age="23";

       $data = array("name"=>"$name","age"=>"$age");
        header("Content-Type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($data);
   ?>
```

This is how my new `submitHandler` looks like

```
     submitHandler : function(){                     
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        cache:false,  
        url: "submitForm.php",  
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {                       
               var name= html(name);
               var age=html(age);

         $("#message").load("newpage.php",{name:name,age:age});

        } 
    });
}
```

I think I am doing it wrong, I would be grateful if somebody could correct me or give an idea as to how to do this. Thanks

Comment: Is this "new page" a new window or tab? or you mean use the returned data from `submitForm.php` to be displayed in the element `$("#message")`?

Comment: @DIEGOCARRASCAL It is using the returned data for another sql query, which is displayed in the element  `$("#message")`

Comment: Then you shouldn't have any problem just displaying it, Hakan SONMEZ answer points the error in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be like this. If you want to take your returner data you should use formal parameter of success function.

```
submitHandler : function(){                     
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        cache:false,  
        url: "submitForm.php",  
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data) {                       
               var name= data.name;
               var age=data.age;

         $("#message").load("newpage.php",{name:name,age:age});

        } 
    });
}
```

Edit: Also you need dataType: 'json' line.

Comment: Thanks @Hakan SONMEZ, I am grateful